# How to display related One to Many Instances in ListView?

Tags: django, django-templates, foreign-keys, one-to-many

I want to display all belonging Instances of model `Report` referenced to model `Module` referenced to  model `Course`. Therefore I implemented three Models related via Foreignkey.

```
class Course(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
```

```
class Module(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    course_id = models.ForeignKey(
        Course,
        null=True,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        related_name="modules",
        default=uuid.uuid4,
    )
```

```
class Report(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    module_id = models.ForeignKey(
        Module,
        null=True,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        related_name="reports",
        default=uuid.uuid4,
    )
```

I want to display model `Module` referenced to  model `Course` in `CourseDetailView(DetailView):`

Here is what I implemented:

```
class CourseDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Course
    context_object_name = "course"
    template_name = "course/course_detail.html"
    fields = ["title", "description"]

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(CourseDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context["courses"] = Course.objects.filter(pk=self.kwargs.get("pk"))
        return context
```

and I get the instance belonging to itsself.

If I change the `context` to:

```
context["modules"] = Module.objects.all()
```

and iterate over `modules` in `course_detail.html`:

```
    {{ course.description|safe }}

    {% for module in modules %}
    <div>
        <h2><a href="{{ module.get_absolute_url }}">{{ modules.title }}</a></h2>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
```

I'll get all instances of Module but I want only the ones related to the specific Course.

I know I have to filter `context["modules"]` but I don't know how to do it.

Due to the fact that I want to display the modules in `CourseDetailView` I am not able to get `module.pk` via `super(CourseDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)`.

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understood you need smth like Module.objects.filter(course_id=id), where id is the id of specific Cource. This queryset is a common case. As you said in comments for your case needed: Module.objects.filter(course_id=self.object)

Comment: Thanks for reply.
I get the error:
['“<built-in function id>” is not a valid UUID.']

Comment: That is a common qs, try: course_id=kwargs.get('id').

Comment: I got it. I had to set course_id = self.object.
Thank you very much for the hint with the common qs.

When you edit your answer to =self.object I could mark it as accepted.